# Accessing listview items from another form

Tags: c#, listview

Let's consider I have two forms: `Form1` and `Form2`.
On `Form1` I have a listview `DataVisualizationList`.
If I want to work with selected items of the listview from `Form1`, `foreach (ListViewItem dr in DataVisualizationList.SelectedItems)` works perfectly. 
How to do the same from `Form2` ?

Comment: Pass list of Form1 to Form2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to either have a reference to `Form1` in `Form2` and have the `DataVisualizationList` be publicly accessable, or have a reference to `DataVisualizationList` in `Form2`.

You could to this with member references.

You would have to set the reference of Form1 in Form2.

Something like this inside Form1

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.f1 = this;
    f2.Show();
}
```

And then inside Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form1 f1;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (f1 != null)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem dr in f1.DataVisualizationList.SelectedItems)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: f1.DataVisualizationList.SelectedItems - is still not recognized

Comment: Did you ensure that the accessor of `DataVisualizationList` is `public` and not `private`?

Comment: thanks, done. I just forgot to switch the modifiers of the listview.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by exposing the `ListView` public, but *don't do that*. Instead expose a property in Form for selected items.

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    public ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection ListViewSelectedItems
    {
        get { return yourListView.SelectedItems; }
    }
}

class Form2 : Form
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        Form1 myForm1Instance = ...;//Get instance somehow
        var items = myForm1Instance.ListViewSelectedItems;//Use it
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
           //Do whatever
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what about "myForm2Instance"? What is that?

Comment: @Mike Check my update, It is the instance of the form which contains your listview

Answer (score 0):

Simplest Solution

### on Form1

```
list<your_Type> li = ListView1.items.ToList()
Form2 frm = new Form2(li);
Frm.Show();
```

### on Form2

```
list<your_Type> li2;
Form2(List<your_Type> li)
 {
 InitializeComponent();
 li2 = li;
 }
```